# How to manually set dirty flag on specific cells in GridPanel in ExtJs

Tags: gridview, extjs, flags, dirty-data

I have a grid panel that is populated with some data from store. This grid has some columns editable. Every row has a button to save editable data.

***My problem is***: 
when I edit more rows and wont to save just one row (because I don't have one button for all rows), the dirty flag (red arrow in corner) disappears from all other edited cells because in my controller I have `store.commitChanges()` method called. When I check the store, there are not dirty data anymore. I tried to catch rowIndex of dirty data before committing and to set committed rows again in dirty, but nothing happens.
I use CellEdit plugin for editing.

***My question is:*** Is there a way to update just one row in store and grid panel? I don't want to reload or load store again.

***After editing :***
[image: see image here] 
***After saving :***
[image: image after saving]

Comment: In you controller you can try to [commit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#method-commit) only the record on the row that has been clicked and this way all other records will remain dirty. Is this what you mean by "update just one row"?

Comment: @scebotari66 Thanks man for fast respond :). Yes this was what I was looking for. I saw this method in Sencha, but I tried with store.commit() end error appears... Instead, I should to call store.getAt(rowIndex).commit(). How can I to put your answer as Resolve / best answer?

Comment: Great to know it helped! I will put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling the store's [commitChanges](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-commitChanges) you mark all records as "commited", meaning that they are not "dirty" anymore.

You should use the model's [commit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#method-commit) method in your case, to commit the changes for each targeted record separately.